# DFS Tree of an Undirected Graph

Tags: algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

So I am given what is a DFS Tree of an Undirected Graph.
Here is the problem:
[image]

Now I already know that the answer is (4,3)

But what other edges not listed would be impossible?

Would (3,6) be a valid edge?
What about (2,4) or (3,5)

Would it be correct to assume that nodes on different branches of a DFS tree cannot have an edge connecting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph `G(V, E)`, as stated in the original question, is undirected. Consider any pair of nodes `u, v \in V` such that **there is** an edge `(u, v) \in E`. Now lets traverse the graph in DFS (depth-first search):

- if we reach `u` first, we will eventually visit all nodes that are reachable from `u`, including `v`, and therefore `v` will be a child node of `u` (or of its child nodes) in the DFS tree;
- if we reach `v` first, the case is analogous, as the graph is undirected.

So, for any edge `(u, v) \in E`, there will be a path in the DFS tree connecting `u` to `v`. Now lets see your cases:

1) *Would (3,6) be a valid edge? What about (2,4) or (3,5)?*

- (3, 6): is not a valid edge. If there were such edge, 3 would be a child node of 6;
- (2, 4): is not a valid edge. If there were such edge, 2 would be a child node of 4;
- (3, 5): is not a valid edge. If there were such edge, 3 would be a child node of 5.

2) *Would it be correct to assume that nodes on different branches of a DFS tree cannot have an edge connecting them?*

If there is an edge connecting two nodes `u` and `v` in an undirected graph, there will be a path `e1 e2 ... en` connecting `u` to `v` (or `v` to `u`) in the associate DFS tree. So, if two nodes from the DFS tree are on different branches, there is no edge inbetween them.